# C# Http Request with array in json

Tags: c#, api, rest, web

I just been exposed to REST API in C#. This must be a very basic question. So I'm doing a http POST request that requires the following json format in the body:

```
{
"cars": [
   {
    "carsRego": "ABC123"
   }
 ]
}
```

How do I serialize it? I came up with this but it's giving me Error 422: Unprocessable Entity error.

```
var cars = new[]
                {
                    new
                    {
                        carsRego = "ABC123"
                    }
                };
        

        using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()))
        {
            string json = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(new
            {
                cars
            }); 

            streamWriter.Write(json);
        }
```

Thank you!

Comment: Code show in the post is extremely unlike to produce the error mentioned. Please review [MCVE] guidance on posting code and [edit] the question accordingly. Side note: Most people use Newtonsoft.Json - while it is definitely not a problem here consider switching as it will give you much more samples/chances to find answers.

Comment: If this is an API endpoint you are returing the json from, use `return JsonResult(myActualData);`

Comment: Use System.Text.Json. Example: string jsonString = `JsonSerializer.Serialize(cars);` You must install by nuget

Comment: Side note: you should use System.Text.Json or Newtonsoft.Json instead of JavaScriptSerializer, per [Microsoft recommendations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: @AugustoFerbonink depending on the target framework, it's not necessary to install by nuget, it's native.

Comment: @Magnetron i think its native only in .net 5.0

Comment: I can't install the System.Text.Json as my project is in .NET Framework 4.5. Updating to higher version may mess the scripts that I have written. So my option is Newtonsoft.Json.

Comment: Check updated answer to contemplate .net  4.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If are you using
.NET 5.0/6.0
.NET core 3.0 or 3.1

Use `System.Text.Json`

Example:

`string jsonString = JsonSerializer.Serialize(cars);`

If are you using
.NET Standard 2.0 or late
.NET Framework 4.7.2 or late
.NET Core 2.0, 2.1 e 2.2

you must install System.Text.Json by nuget

If are you using .net framework 4.7.2 or earlier use newtonsoft.json: https://www.newtonsoft.com/, or install by nuget.

Example:

```
  using Newtonsoft.Json;
  ...
  var cars = new[]
            {
                new
                {
                    carsRego = "ABC123"
                }
            };

   string output = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(cars);
```

Comment: You're welcome. Please mark this answer as right answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

create class

```
public class CarsRegistration
{
    public string carsRego {get; set;}
}
```

now you can use this code

```
var cars = new Dictionary<string, CarsRegistration[]>
            {
             { "cars",  new CarsRegistration[]
                {
                    new CarsRegistration{ carsRego = "ABC123"}
                }
                }
            };

string output = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(cars);

var carsFromJson= JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, 
     CarsRegistration[]>> (output);

output = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(carsFromJson);
```

output

```
{"cars":[{"carsRego":"ABC123"}]}
```